# Cursor Adapter selecting the wrong items to delete?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

So I know this question has been posted a few times on the site, but my case si a little different.

Suppose I have these items in my cursor
(in order)
:

```
Alaska
Canada
United States of America
Mongolia
China
India
```

When I click Alaska, log shows Mongolia is clicked,
and right after that, if I select Canada, it shows Mongolia was clicked

and then after I click Mongolia, United States of America was clicked instead

It is having this weird behavior above.
Here is my code for my Cursor Adapter:

```
public class EventListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;
    Calculations calculations = new Calculations();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Context AppContext;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    Context mContext;
    String[] whereClause;
    Intent mainActivityIntent;

    public EventListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        AppContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mContext = context;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView timeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
        TextView nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        TextView dateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
        TextView summaryText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_summary);
        TextView locationText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_location);
        TextView categoryText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_category);
        CardView card = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.CardViewItem);

        final Cursor mCursor = cursor;

        String date = calculations.UnixTimeConverter(
                mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_UNIXTIME)
        ))[0];
        String time = calculations.UnixTimeConverter(
                mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_UNIXTIME))
        )[1];
        final LatLng location = gson.fromJson(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_LOCATION)),LatLng.class);

        nameText.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME)));

        Log.i("bindView cursor check", "name=" + mCursor.getString((mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME))));

        dateText.setText(date);
        timeText.setText(time);
        summaryText.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_SUMMARY)));
        locationText.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_LOCATIONNAME)));
        categoryText.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_CATEGORY)));

        locationText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final CameraPosition camLocation  = CameraPosition.builder().target(location).zoom(18).build();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camLocation));
            }
        });

        summaryText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater mLayoutInflator;
                mLayoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(AppContext);
                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                View mView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.summarydialog,null);

                TextView textView = mView.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
                textView.setText(
                        mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_SUMMARY))
                );

                textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        card.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                whereClause = new String[] {String.valueOf(mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_LOCALID)))};
                Log.v("Where clause:",whereClause[0]);

                Log.i("Event onLongClick", "name=" + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME)));

                LayoutInflater mLayoutInflator;
                mLayoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(AppContext);
                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                View mView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.canceldelete_editor,null);

                final TextView cancelButton = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.cancelAction);
                final TextView deleteButton = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.deleteEntryAction);

                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                dialog.show();
                dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        Log.v("Where clause changed:",whereClause[0]);
                    }
                });
                cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                Log.v("Item Lond Clicked",mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME)));
                deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        int tru = db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COL_LOCALID + " = " + mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_LOCALID)), null);
                        Log.v("Deleting Item:",mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME))+"");

                        if(tru == 1){
                            Log.v("Delete: ", "SuccessFull!" + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME)));
                        }else{
                            Log.v("Delete: ", "Failed!" + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME)));
                        }

                        DataSenderToServer dataSenderToServer = new DataSenderToServer();
                        dataSenderToServer.eraseEntry(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_GLOBALID)));
                        mainActivityIntent = new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        mCursor.requery();
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        });
```

How do I choose the right item to delete from the cursor adapter?
Some help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

A Cursor is just a result set from the database with a position pointer into the current row. As you scroll your list and new rows are filled in based on your cursor data, this position pointer is automatically moved for you under the covers.so save your cursor position in bindView method.

Change your onClickListener in bindView like blow

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    final int position = cursor.getPosition();

     deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                         cursor.moveToPosition(position);

                           //Now Do Your delete operation 
                        }
                    });

}
```